# Getting All possible bit combinations of bit-size N

Tags: python, python-3.x

To test a full-adder I am combining all possible 0 or 1 inputs in three ways (one for input_a, one for input_b, and one for carry_c). To do this I am doing:

```
>>> [(bit1, bit2, bit3) for bit1 in a for bit2 in a for bit3 in a]
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]
```

This works fine, but my two thoughts on this are:

- Is there a more pythonic way to do this. Something like a built in `combinations([0,1], 3)`?
- Would there be a way to abstract the list-comprehension so that for example I could do 20 possibilities without having to write it 20 times?

I've looked a bit at `itertools` but it seems like using that for the above case requires just about as much code (if not more) as the above list comprehension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`product` from `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) (Cartesian product):

```
from itertools import product

print(list(product([0, 1], repeat=3)))
```

Output:

```
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]
```

To change how many elements there are per tuple, you can alter the `repeat` argument.

Comment: oh great, `product` -- yes that's what I was looking for, thanks!